# Crawl live website and do a text/code search?

Tags: software-recommendation, websites

I need a Mac app that can crawl a live website and do a text search (and, as a bonus, a source code search) and report the results.

Surely something like this exists. Help!

Answer (score -1):

When I needed to do this I used AppleScript to feed the text to BBEdit which has a full POSIX regex and excellent AppleScript support. You can probably do it with Automator as well and simply use `due shellscript` to pipe the text through your regex.

Comment: Care to share !

Comment: Unless you can provide the details, this isn't really what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, this isn't really the palce to post a lot of Applescript, but the command I used was `tell safari to set TheUrl to URL of document 1 as string` and then I used `do shell script "curl \"" & TheUrl & "\""` and then `set PageSource to the result` From there, it's scripting BBEdit to massage the source code.